# Is there an HttpClient that handles caching requests on its own?

Tags: java, android, httpclient, http-caching

I have an app that needs to make repeated requests for content on the web. Now the server side implementation follows the standards for http caching using the headers. I was wondering if there is an extended version of HttpClient or another tool that will store responses and interact with the headers for automatic caching. If there isn't one that is fine, I would just like to skip implementing this if there is a tool already out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apache HttpClient does introduce [CachingHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient-cache/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/CachingHttpClient.html) since 4.1, But Android only include 4.0.x by default and will not maintain HttpClient in the future. From my point of view, I don't see any constrains that prevent us manually import and use it with Android SDK.

The recommended way is to use HttpURLConnection, as stated in their official blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

EDIT:

A nice tutorial [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html)
Download Page [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)
A note from its official website [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/):

> **End of life**
>   The Commons HttpClient project is now end of life, and is no longer being developed. It has been replaced by the Apache HttpComponents project in its HttpClient and HttpCore modules, which offer better performance and more flexibility.

Good luck, I had a quick try several month ago, but didn't get it quite successful (it seems only work with standard web server running on port 80, not with my custom one).

Comment: CachingHttpClient looks perfect for what I would like. I have been looking around for a jar but cannot find one to include. Would you suggest finding the source for all the files needed and just adding them to my app?

Comment: Thanks this is working perfect if I cache into memory. Now I am trying to implement a HttpCacheStorage to write cache to disk. I am running into issues because even though HttpCacheEntry implements Serializable it fails to serialize when the writeObject call is made. I am going to move this to another question because I feel you have answered my original, thanks.

Comment: @Bobbake4, glad to see your efforts and positive feedback, although I would probably drop HttpClient and move to HttpURLConnection in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly the Google Data Libraries have one. Not sure if it interacts with the headers.