# Implementing a HttpCacheStorage correctly?

Tags: java, android, http

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525496/is-there-an-httpclient-that-handles-caching-requests-on-its-own) question earlier and was answered but I have run into issues relating to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525496/is-there-an-httpclient-that-handles-caching-requests-on-its-own) question. I am trying to implement a HttpCacheStorage to write cache to disk. If I use in memory caching everything works fine but I would like to persist the cache after leaving my application. I am running into issues because even though HttpCacheEntry implements Serializable it fails to serialize when the writeObject call is made. Has anyone used CachingHttpClient and implemented their own HttpCacheStorage correctly? If so can you give me some pointers on how to write an object to disk if it will not serialize.

Comment: Your last 2 link point to your computer's file system :)

Comment: Can you post your code with CachingHttpClient using and error stacktrace?

Answer (score -1):

Could you not simply use `org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage`, which according to its JavaDoc:

> allows for spillover to disk, where the cache can be effectively
>   larger than memory, and cached responses are paged into and out of
>   memory from disk as needed

?