# catch response from web service

Tags: android, httpresponse

i make a web service to my application,,my response is "SUCCESS" and "FAILURE"
and i want to catch response from my service into my application
if my response "SUCCESS" i do something,but if "FAILURE" nothing do something
i try with :
 `(request(response) != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)`
 not working,because it's just read network status **ok** or **not**..
how can i do this??
this is my full code :

```
public void getRequest(String Url) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data " + request(response) + " ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (request(response) != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            if(response.getEntity().equals("SUCCESS")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Inisialisasi sukses", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*helper.insertUser(noImei.getText().toString(),user.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
                startActivity(new Intent(UserForm.this,MenuUtama.class));
                user.setText("");
                password.setText("");*/
                System.out.println("sukses");
            }else if(response.getEntity().equals("FAILURE")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("GAGAL");
            }

        }/*else if(request(response) != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 408){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/else if(request(response) != null && response.getStatusLine().equals("FAILURE"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Inisialisasi "+request(response), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data Gagal !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}

public static String request(HttpResponse response) {

    String result = "";
    try {
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            str.append(line + "\n");

        }
        in.close();
        result = str.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = "Error";
        }
        return result;

}
```

thank you for feed back :)

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525496/is-there-an-httpclient-that-handles-caching-requests-on-its-own/8525608#8525608) helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

When HttpResponse came back, you just need to check whether you are getting response and whether the response is [HttpStatus.SC_OK](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html#SC_OK)(200). After you get that, you parse entity and check "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE". In your code, your comparing Entity Object with "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE".

Please mind my indentation. I just made changes to your original posted code.

```
  public void getRequest(String Url) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data " + request(response) + " ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            String res = request(response);
            if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Inisialisasi sukses", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*helper.insertUser(noImei.getText().toString(),user.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
                startActivity(new Intent(UserForm.this,MenuUtama.class));
                user.setText("");
                password.setText("");*/
                System.out.println("sukses");
            }else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("FAILURE")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("GAGAL");
            }

        }/*else if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 408){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Inisialisasi "+response.getStatusLine(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data Gagal !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public static String request(HttpResponse response) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line + "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        result = str.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = "Error";
        }
        return result;

}
}
```

Comment: i try to do like your code,but it's still doesn't work..my application doesn't do anything..can you give another suggest??thank you :) @PH7

Comment: Did you get any error? Show me what do you get. It'll help in analyzing the problem.

Comment: i didn't get any errors..but my application not do anything..in logCat i get message like this `04-30 09:26:52.669: INFO/global(2388): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
` what should i do??thank you :)

Comment: my application not do anything, whereas i insert activity if response from my service **SUCCESS**..please help me..thank you :) @PH7

Comment: it's solved!!in part `String res = request(respones);` i modify with `String res = UntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());` and it's work!!:) thank you