# what is the best way to Cache data for android client server application

Tags: android, caching

I need to know if I have client server android application and I want to cache data to improve the performance of the app..what is the best way to do this ??
my services is PHP web services and I retrieve data from it in JSON arrays

Thank you .

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525496/is-there-an-httpclient-that-handles-caching-requests-on-its-own/8525608#8525608) helps.